When trying to unload i2c-bcm2835 module dynamically in raspberry pi I'm always getting the "rmmod: ERROR: Module i2c_bcm2835 is in use"
I made some changes in the i2c_bcm2835.c file and now I want to dynamically load this module, i2c-bcm2835.ko which I got from below,
obj-m += i2c-bcm2835.o
all:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) modules
clean:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) clean

And when I run the below python script,
import os
os.system("make")
os.system("sudo cp i2c-bcm2835.ko /lib/modules/5.10.110-v7l/kernel/drivers/i2c/busses/i2c-bcm2835.ko")
os.system("sudo depmod -a")
os.system("sudo rmmod i2c-bcm2835")
os.system("sudo modprobe i2c-bcm2835")

I either get the following error or the script gets stuck forever
rmmod: ERROR: Module i2c_bcm2835 is in use

Is i2c-bcm2835 always in use? actually can we even load the i2c-bcm2835 module dynamically?
And with below info I think i2c-bcm2835 is not used by anything currently?
lsmod | grep i2c
i2c_mux_pinctrl        16384  0
i2c_mux                16384  1 i2c_mux_pinctrl
i2c_bcm2835            16384  0
i2c_dev                20480  0

lsof | grep i2c //this didn't give anything either

Using modprobe -r didn't work too. Should I try to force the removal of the module would it be fine? And I've seen the changes I made in the i2c-bcm2835.c come into effect after reboot. But I want to do it dynamically.
Help.
P.S. I don't have any i2c devices connected to the pi
